# How to connect two computers wirelessly

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, arch-linux, streaming, raspberry-pi

I want to connect my Raspberry on which I installed archlinux arm, wirelessly to my computer. With this connection I want to stream a live video from the Raspberry Pi.

```
Raspberry<------Wireless connection (direct)----->Laptop
```

The video stream is easy. I managed to set it up with an Ethernet connection.
I haven't any guide how to connect the raspberry and the laptop wirelessly with Archlinux.

It is possible?

Comment: What OS is on the laptop? You need to create an ad-hoc wireless network between your RaspberryPi and your laptop (because you don't have a wireless router in the middle) - ArchLinux instructions: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ad-hoc_networking. You can then connect to this network with your laptop and it'll be the client.

Comment: It's called wi-fi...

Comment: @jiggunjer - can you elaborate?

Comment: My laptop also runs with archlinux.

Comment: I did it myself with hostapd (the tool create_ap (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Software_access_point#create_ap)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a software called *motion* that will give everything you need to stream live video.

Install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install motion
```

It has a daemon that captures the video through the camera and stream it, so anyone on the network can watch it.

**EDIT:** I've found [this tutorial](https://rbnrpi.wordpress.com/project-list/setting-up-wireless-motion-detect-cam/) that gives you a step-by-step guide to do it.

Comment: I really know how to setup motion. The problem is the direct connection between the raspberry and the laptop.

Comment: *motion* streams through a port that you can connect to using a browser. According to the mencioned tutorial: `... if you start a browser on another computer on your local network (Internet Explorer doesn’t work but Chrome, Firefox and Safari are ok) you should see live pictures at http://192.168.1.98:8081`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set one of the Linux boes to act as an Access point.  You can find a tutorial [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Software_access_point). to do it in Arch Linux.   or alternatively [here](http://xmodulo.com/raspberry-pi-wifi-access-point.html) is one to do it on the Pi.    In a nutshell you need to use HostAPD to turn one of the devices into the AP so the other device connects to it as a regular client.

Most WIFI devices won't work in a straight bridging-to-each-other mode which is outside the spec of 802.11a/b/g/n/ac - particularly not in computers.